# How to remove words in PHP that contain Non-Alphabet characters from a string?

Tags: php, regex, string, alpha

How would I remove entire words from a string that contain characters that are not from the alphabet?

**Edit** However, `'` and `-` should be the only characters that are allowed alongside the alphabet.

E.g: `This is a? #test e3ample`

Becomes: `This is`

The solutions I have found are focused on removing specific characters from a string rather than the whole word.

I have tried creating an array with banned characters but that is bad practice. How would I do so with Regex? Or something similar.

Comment: from the above string, what would you remove?

Comment: @rtfm So any word that contains anything other than letters from the alphabet will be removed. If a word has both letters and numbers (or special characters) for example, it should be removed. I have now made the edit, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: hyphenated words? and you want to remove punctuation as well?

Comment: @rtfm `-` and `'` should be allowed. I'll update the question details to add those in

Comment: accents? Café for example

Comment: @rtfm Nope, remove those

Comment: @Gurman your pattern needs more refinement.  Add a valid word to the end of an input string and you will get 2 consecutive spaces in the output.  Please do not post solutions as comments - we cannot downvote faulty commented solutions.  Please remove.

Comment: @mickmackusa It was just a matter of removing the lookbehind and actually matching the space or start of the string. Anyways, removed the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try doing a regex replacement with the following pattern:

```
(?=[^ ]*[^A-Za-z \'-])([^ ]*)(?:\\s+|$)
```

This uses a lookahead to check if each word contains a non alpha character.  If so, then it will remove that entire word.  Dashes and single quotes are also allowed.

```
$input = "H3llo This is a? #test e3ample of a sentence-word bl&h.";
echo preg_replace('/(?=[^ ]*[^A-Za-z \'-])([^ ]*)(?:\\s+|$)/', '', $input);

This is of a sentence-word
```

### Demo

**Edit:**

If at some future point you need to add allowed characters to your list (besides dash and single apostrophe), then just add them to the character class.  E.g. to also allow period and comma then use this pattern:

```
(?=[^ ]*[^A-Za-z \'.,-])([^ ]*)(?:\\s+|$)
```

Comment: Tried your demo with valid `blah` trailed by a period.  Bonk.  Because there are no word boundaries I presume.   ...wait, does the OP want it like that?  Seems sloppy to me.

Comment: @mickmackusa `However, ' and - should be the only characters that are allowed alongside the alphabet.` ... period is not allowed AFAIK.  "Bonk" is a rude comment.

Comment: My mistake.  Apologies.  Good answer to an incomplete question - no coding attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Simply write a match for consecutive characters that would *not* fit the "word" definition, such as:

- any non-spacy characters `\S*`
- a negated list of allowed chars `[^-a-z\s]` plus space
- non-spacy characters `\S*`

The trick being that any non-space string will get matched, as long as it does contain one character that's not in the allowed set.

Answer (score 0):

By my tests this pattern is leanest because it avoids lookarounds and capture groups.  If it doesn't work for all cases, please comment to me the string that breaks it.

Demo:  https://regex101.com/r/h9w3xn/5

Pattern:

```
/\S*[^a-z '-]\S* | \S*[^a-z '-]\S*/i
```

(No replacement string)

This will match the invalid substrings and either the leading or trailing space (but never both) to generate a clean output string.

One might comment that this isn't a very DRY pattern because it repeats itself, but the advantages are: efficiency and I think readability.

Answering from my phone; correct me if I am wrong.